# Pandas. DataFrame.groupby('column').sum() puts all information in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple DataFrame with two columns: timestampx (a DateTime value) and length (a float value).
The DataFrame covers about 80 seconds of time, and so there are 80 unique values in the timestampx column. The length column is all unique values. The number of rows varies.

```
print("***Before groupby")
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

***Before groupby
<bound method NDFrame.head of                timestampx   length
0     2021-05-25 06:43:31  0.11328
1     2021-05-25 06:43:31  0.00864
2     2021-05-25 06:43:31  0.07872
3     2021-05-25 06:43:31  0.00864
4     2021-05-25 06:43:31  0.00896
...                   ...      ...
3532  2021-05-25 06:44:50  0.00864
3533  2021-05-25 06:44:50  0.00896
3534  2021-05-25 06:44:50  0.00768
3535  2021-05-25 06:44:50  0.00896
3536  2021-05-25 06:44:50  0.00768

[3537 rows x 2 columns]>
Index(['timestampx', 'length'], dtype='object')
```

I need the total length per second. I can do this using the groupby() and sum() functions. However, those functions condense the DataFrame into one column.

```
df = df.groupby('timestampx').sum() 
print("***Afer groupby")
print(df.head)
print(df.columns)

***After groupby
<bound method NDFrame.head of                       length
timestampx
2021-05-25 06:43:31  0.97024
2021-05-25 06:43:32  1.04960
2021-05-25 06:43:33  1.08416
2021-05-25 06:43:34  1.04960
2021-05-25 06:43:35  1.27872
...                      ...
2021-05-25 06:44:46  1.17080
2021-05-25 06:44:47  1.04960
2021-05-25 06:44:48  1.11296
2021-05-25 06:44:49  1.26176
2021-05-25 06:44:50  1.11520

[80 rows x 1 columns]>
Index(['length'], dtype='object')
```

Before groupby is called, there are two columns. After groupby is called, there is only one column. The number of rows is correct, and the data in each row is correct. But it's all jammed into one column.

Because the new DataFrame has only one column, a command like this:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scattergl(x=df['timestampx'], y=df['length'], mode='markers'))
```

fails because df no longer has an index named 'timestampx'.

Is there a way to sum one column by unique values in another column, while preserving the number of columns?

Comment: You can put `as_index=False` as a parameter of `.groupby( )`

Comment: Thanks! So many times it just a simple parameter that I'm not aware of. I really appreciate your help.